# Finding a Condition on $S(r)$ if $R'(0)=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

> I am trying to solve  $\ rR''+2R'+rR\lambda=0\ $, given $R(1)=0$ and $R'(0)=0$.

I let $S(r)=rR$ which gave the ODE
$$S''(r)+\lambda S(r)=0.$$
I know wish to solve this problem, but I'm having trouble converting the boundary condition $R'(0)=0$ into a condition on $S(r)$. If $R(1)=0\implies S(1)=0$. But how does
$$R'(r)=\frac{rS'(r)-S(r)}{r^2}\Bigg|_{r=0}$$ relate to a boundary condition for $S(r)$?

Comment: Differentiating $S$ yields $S'(r)=R(r)+rR'(r)$, right? You then have $S'(0)=R(0)$

Comment: @RMWGNE96 If I'm trying to solve $$S(r)=Ar+B,$$ how does $S'(0)=R(0)$ help?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is a constant, then $S(r)$ is of the form $S(r)=A\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\cdot r+\phi_1)+B\cos(-\sqrt{\lambda}\cdot r+\phi_2)$

Comment: @RMWGNE96 Yes, I know this. But I'd like to show formally that $\lambda=0$ and $\lambda<0$ result in trivial solutions. Hence my original question.

Comment: You have $R(r)=A+B/r$ using your earlier Ansatz for $S(r)$, right? Differentiating gives $R'(r)=-B/r^2$ and this indeed is a problem because we cannot substitute $r=0$...

Comment: @RMWGNE96 So $S$ must be finite as $r\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: I guess, but then $A=B=0$ so there is nothing interesting anymore...